# AWS SAM does not create and set default models automatically

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, aws-sam

How can I create both (Empty and Error) default models and set Empty model in my lambda functions on AWS SAM template, like happens when I create an API Gateway/Resource in AWS website?

AWS SAM creates an empty method response, like this. (It is in Portuguese)

[image]